# opencv_perf_stitching_Release.gch not generated by cmakefiles

Tags: c++, opencv, windows-7, cmake, mingw32

I am trying to configure openCV with codeblocks but It got stuck during mingw32-make step, giving me this error:

> [ 94%] Generating
>   perf_precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_perf_stitching_Release.gch
>   C:/openCV/opencv/build/x86/mingw/modules/stitching/perf_precomp.hpp:1:0:
>   fatal error: can't creat e precompiled header
>   C:/opeCV/opencv/build/x86/mingw/modules/stitching/perf_precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_perf_stitching_Release.gch:
>   No such file or directory  #ifdef __GNUC__  ^ compilation terminated.
>   modules\stitching\CMakeFiles\pch_Generate_opencv_perf_stitching.dir\build.make:61:
>   recipe for tar get
>   'modules/stitching/perf_precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_perf_stitching_Release.gch'
>   failed mingw32-make[2]: ***
>   [modules/stitching/perf_precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_perf_stitching_Release.gch]
>   E rror 1 CMakeFiles\Makefile2:6569: recipe for target
>   'modules/stitching/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_pe
>   rf_stitching.dir/all' failed mingw32-make[1]: ***
>   [modules/stitching/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_perf_stitching.dir/all]
>   Er ror 2 Makefile:159: recipe for target 'all' failed mingw32-make:
>   *** [all] Error 2

I am unable to resolve it!

I am using windows 7 32bit

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar problem that may be caused by cmd input limitation.
The cmd input limitation in win7 is about 8000 characters and in most case that is enough.

However in opencv build,one built component (opencv_perf_stitching_Release) might break this limition due to a long executed command.Because of different folder length for different users,the cutting point in executed command is located at unfixed position.Their error messages are also totally distinctive.In my example,I got a message `unrecognized command line option '-sse'` but i doubt we met the same problem.

The simplest solutiuon is to reduce your building folder level.In your case,you can change your install path from `C:/opeCV/opencv/` to `C:/opencv/` and try again.